# Nginx location directive not blocking URIs with '..' in the path

Tags: security, nginx, url, webserver, uri

Why does my NGINX location block only work for URIs that like `"https:/domain.com/foo/boo../"`, but not for URIs like `"https:/domain.com/foo/../"`?

```
location ~* \.\./ {
    deny all;
}
```

I am trying to deny every request containing `..` in is path.

Judging from the logs, NGINX is receiving the request with the two dots intact.

Thanks beforehand :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your browser itself "resolves" the two dots found `/../` to a directory level above, so actually when you request "https:/domain.com/foo/../" in your browser, it goes to "https:/domain.com/"

In other words, for a case where two dots are surrounded by slashes, there's no security issue there - NGINX never sees two dots for such case, there's no "filesystem traversal" issue, because simply the client requests a URL.

You only need to secure the serving of hidden files:

```
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Judging from the logs, NGINX is receiving the request with the two dots intact.

Comment: I only mentioned `/../`. The only way you see two dots in the logs is for case `/boo../` where it doesn't present a security issue. For `/../` you can confirm not being sent to server by monitoring chrome developer tools network tab, it reaches server without dots.

Comment: Like I said, it is reaching server with dots, even with `/../`. I am not using a web browser.

Comment: Likewise, if you managed to pass this on, NGINX does what browsers do by normalizing the URL first, so the top-level URL will be fetched (not file system, *not* outside webroot). You're attempting to secure from a non-existent threat. A `/file.php?=../some.php` is a probably path traveral attack, while `/../` isn't.